# How do you combine graphics from tiKZ, PGF and circuiTiKz packages with the regular text as in a document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, circuitikz, text

Most of the examples given in manuals shows only graphics from TiKZ, PGF and circuiTiKZ packages only. There is no single example embedding these graphics in a regular document.

Comment: What do you actually mean? Do you mean text - graphic -text or text within the graphic like text of a node?

Comment: There are also floats (figure), wrapfig, minipage, \raisebox and paracol.

Comment: A Ti*k*Z graphic is, for the rest of the document, just a (maybe big) letter. You can place it more or less where you can place  the letter "A". In text, between paragraph, in floating environments, in tabular... (Well, you can't nest them).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}% loads tikz automatically
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newcommand\atikzpicture{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(Q.B)]%baseline is the base of Q
        \draw (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(0.5,0)
        node[npn, anchor=base](Q){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\begin{document}

Basically a Ti\emph{k}Z picture is a box, and you can put it where you like, even in the \atikzpicture\ flow of text; normally you'll have it between paragraph:

\atikzpicture

In the case above, the picture is basically a paragraph by itself, but you can put it even in a formula:
\begin{equation}
    \atikzpicture
\end{equation}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \atikzpicture
    \caption{Look, mum, a transistor!}
    \label{fig:one}
\end{wrapfigure}
You can clearly put it in a wrap-figure like in this case where I need to add a bit of text to fill the spaces\dots 

Clearly you can use it in a floating figure, so that it can move around in the ``best place'' according to \LaTeX{} point of view\dots

\begin{figure}[htpb!]
    \centering
    \atikzpicture
    \caption{Look, dad, another one!}
    \label{fig:two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Basically, you *can't* put a Ti*k*Z picture inside another one (for example, as the contents of a node), and you need to be quite careful when putting it in moving arguments. But basically --- that it as you will treat, say, an `\includegraphics` and you should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=black,fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle ++(5,2);
    \node at (2.5,1) {hello there};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]  
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. I am familiar with floats, wrapfig, and minipage. I haven't use \raisebox. Writing in LaTeX is really very interesting and challenging. Thanks.